# substr method doesnt work with strpos in php

Tags: php, html

I have to make a php document, which takes apart an email adress. When you have sample@gmail.com for instance this should be shown:

local-part: sample

host: gmail

top-level-domain: com

when I run this code, the second statement doest work really well. Instead of "gmail" i get "gmail.com"

```
<?php $str=$_GET["email"];
echo "local-part: ".substr($str,0,strpos($str,"@"))."<br>";
echo "host: ".substr($str,strpos($str,"@")+1,strpos($str,"."))."<br>";
echo "top-level domain: ".substr($str,strpos($str,".")+1,strlen($str)); ?>
<form method="GET" action="index.php">
<input id="mail" type="text" size="20" name="email">
<input type=submit value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: The third parameter is length, but you're providing a position. `$length = strpos('.') - strpos('@');`

Answer (score 3):

I think this is easier and simpler to do with `explode()`. Split the first string on `@` then split the right side of that on `.`:

```
$str = 'sample@gmail.com';
[$localPart, $domain] = explode('@', $str);
[$host, $tld] = explode('.', $domain);

echo "Local part: $localPart\n";
echo "Host: $host\n";
echo "TLD: $tld\n";
```

Output:

```
Local part: sample
Host: gmail
TLD: com
```

Note this only works when your domain is two levels. If you want to handle things like `foo.gmail.com` then you'll need a bit more:

```
[$localPart, $domain] = explode('@', $str);
$host = substr($domain, 0, strrpos($domain, '.'));
$tld = substr($domain, strrpos($domain, '.') + 1);
```

Output:

```
Local part: sample
Host: foo.gmail
TLD: com
```

Note `strpos()` finds the first occurrence from left-to-right, and `strrpos()` goes right-to-left. You want the latter to find the TLD.

Another example:

```
[$localPart, $domain] = explode('@', $str);
$parts = explode('.', $domain);
$tld = array_pop($parts); // pop off the last thing in the list
$host = implode('.', $parts); // re-join the remaining items
```

Comment: fails on `sample@site.co.jp` and a lot more, but im not saying its not what the user wants

Comment: i still get `TLD: co` from the above using `sample@site.co.jp`

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to this language so I don't know if I did something wrong or the interpreter.

Comment: @tim Oops, misunderstood your comment. Additional samples provided.

Comment: `explode('.', 'foo.bar.baz', 2)` >> `['foo', 'bar.baz']`

Comment: @Sammitch I'm assuming OP wants `['foo.bar', 'baz']` in this case. Would be cool if you could provide a negative value for that arg, so it takes from the right first, instead of the left.

Comment: @AlexHowansky actually with an email addresses like `bob@local.company.co.uk` or `ted@tax.gov.ab.ca` it's even more complicated as to how to properly split the string. At this point I think it's an XY problem we should probably find out why they care about the TLD

Answer (score 0):

Alex's answer explains a better way to do this, but to answer your direct question, of why you're getting the ".com" with your host, the reason is that the [substr()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function accepts the *length* as its third argument, rather than the position to stop within the string.

If you run:

```
echo strpos($str,".");
```

It will output the number 13. So your substr is trying to grab the 13 characters *that follow* the "@", as opposed to grabbing *up to* the 13th character in the string.

Be careful when trying to parse emails. There are a lot of gotchas and obscure rules.